Drupal 7 module to connect 3PL central
I have made a Drupal module to integrate 3pl warehouse
install module at Drupal 7
just need install at Drupal system and configure access from Drupal configuration,
This module connects with Drupal to 3pl automatically.
you may find module from https://github.com/MrKoushikNaikel/3pl.git
